# Novikov self-consistency principle

Tags: spacetime

Does the Novikov self-consistency principle show why there can't be two distinct happenings at the same spacetime point. I.e. why there is also only one history?

Answer (score 0):

By definition of what a spacetime point (usually called an event) *is*, there can not be two distinct happenings there.

A spacetime event is not a place where something can happen, because it also includes the time dimension (it is four-dimensional), so in a sense an event 'happens' in itself (which is why it is called an 'event' in the first place), and as such it can not 'happen' twice at all.

Now when and where it 'happens' depends on the observer, because each observer sees its own division of spacetime into space and time.

The Novikov principle relates to the causal structure of spacetime, that is to the ways spacetime events can be connected (or not) by world lines (timelike curves). Whether there are closed world lines or not, only one history can be associated to such a curve because the events it goes through are static in spacetime.